# handle promises in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise

I am having trouble when using promise.
my controller is

```
angular.module('shoppingPad').controller('customerCtrl', customerCtrl);
function customerCtrl($scope, customerService){

    $scope.addCustomer=function() {
        alert("inside add Customer function");
        var customer={
            name: $scope.name,
            number: $scope.number
        };
         customerService.addCustomer(customer).then(function(response){
          console.log(response);
         },
         function(error){
            console.log(error)
         });
}
```

this is my service

```
angular.module('shoppingPad').service('customerService', customerService);
function customerService($q, $http,restService) {
    //this is deferred object which will resolve or resolve the promise
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    //a function to add customer data to backend used service.it takes customer object as paramater.
    this.addCustomer = function(customer) {
  return restService.postRequest('customers/info',customer,function(response){
        deferred.resolve(response.data); 
       return deferred.promise;
    },
    function(error){
        deferred.reject(error);
        return deferred.promise;
    });
};
```

This is my restService.js

```
angular.module('shoppingPad').service('restService',restService);
function restService($http){
    //set port number and baseUrl here
    var port=3001;
    var baseUrl="http://localhost:"+port;

//generic getRequest function 


this.postRequest=function(url,data,successCallback,failureCallback){
    $http({
        method:'POST',
        url:baseUrl+"/"+url,
        data:data
    }).then(function(response){
        successCallback(response);
    },
    function(error){
        alert("internal server error");
        failureCallback(error);

    });

};//end of postRequest function
}//end of service
```

I am getting error in my controller as 
Error: customerService.addCustomer(...) is undefined.
if Iam doing wrong please correct me with good code

Answer (score 3):

The problem in your code is that you are not returning anything from your `$http()` call in `this.postRequest()` method.

Change your method as below:

```
 this.postRequest=function(url,data){
    return $http({
             method: 'POST',
             url: baseUrl+"/"+url,
             data: data
           });

 };
```

Don't pass success and error callbacks in this but just return the promise from this upstream method and handle the promise. Also, since every return of this promise will be a promise in itself you don't need to create a new promise using `$q` in your `customerService`. Just return the same promise from `postRequest` method as below:

```
this.addCustomer = function(customer) {
  return restService.postRequest('customers/info', customer);
}
```

This way you don't need additional unnecessary promises.

Now in your controller you can handle the returned promise as below:

```
$scope.addCustomer=function() {
  alert("inside add Customer function");
  var customer={
        name: $scope.name,
        number: $scope.number
  };

  customerService.addCustomer(customer)
   .then(function(response){
     console.log(response);
   })
   .catch(function(error){
     console.log(error)
   });
}
```

Also I have used `.catch` instead of passing the error callback as second parameter to `.then` because it has an added advantage of *catch*ing errors in the success callback along with any errors from returned promise

Comment: I don't think he knows how to *handle* the promise. If he knew he wouldn't be asking this. Maybe you need to add an example for that as well.

Comment: @TJ Done. Added handler in controller